# Backbone.js change event not firing when value is same as previous value prior to null set

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

1) Set the model data to a value `model.set({state : 'wa'})`

2) Set the model data to null `model.set({state : null})`

3) Set the model data to first value `model.set({state : 'wa'})`

The change event isn't fired when you set the model data to the previous value prior to setting it to null. If I changed the example to show `model.set({state : 'ca'})` in step 1, it would fire a change event for all three sets. In this example, only two change events are fired, for step 1 and step 2 only.

Why won't backbone fire an event when setting the value to the previous one prior to null?

## P.S.

I just checked the `model.previousAttrbutes()` to see if maybe it doesn't update when setting a value to null. It does. So it still doesn't make sense why the change event isn't fired.

Comment: Seems to be working in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyclone009/nyhVg/). Anything different you're doing ? May be assigning `null` value is being prevented by `validators` preventing the `set` of the attribute leaving the attribute with the old value, hence not firing the change. Not sure, just A may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, I simply used `unset()`

```
model.unset('state',{silent: true});
```